# What is the difference between yum update -- security and yum update-minimal --security?

Tags: security, yum

I was reading the documentation regarding the yum update section in RHEL8 , I found both these commands ,
it was written in the documentation :

`yum update         --security`  : to upgrade to the latest available packages that have security errata

`yum update-minimal --security`  : to upgrade to the last security errata packages

I can't understand the difference between th two statements , please if any one elaborate it will be
helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that :

```
yum update --security
```

Will update any package that have at least one errata to the latest available version.

Meanwhile :

```
yum update-minimal --security
```

Will update any package to the exact version where the last errata is fixed /  remediated.

Comment: you mean that "minimal" refers to the version ? meaning minimal version were the errata is fixed ?

Comment: yes exactly ;) that what i meant it's the version that remediated to the errata.

Comment: I'd like to ask u another little question , by security errata do the documentation mean security fxes for any package or security fixes to security software related packages like firewall or selinux ..etc ?

Comment: it means for all your system packaes including security ones.